# Can I create a MYSQL select statement with a column which consists on another select statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to export some data from an old Drupal site. I was hoping I could get a MYSQL query like this:

`SELECT users.uid, name, pass, mail, created, (SELECT rid FROM users_roles WHERE users_roles.uid = users.uid) AS all_rids
FROM users`

So a row of output might be something like:

`"1000", "Frank Smith", "123456", "frank@example.com", "12/15/2012", "3,7,12"`

The point is that the last column is an array consisting of values from a select statement

...Sorry, I forget the proper terminology for this type of query, but I am pretty sure something like this is possible in SQL Server.

Is this possible in MYSQL? If so, what syntax?

Answer (score 0):

There may be multiple matches.  I think you want to use `group_concat()` in the subquery:

```
SELECT users.uid, name, pass, mail, created,
       (SELECT group_concat(rid)
        FROM users_roles
        WHERE users_roles.uid = users.uid
       ) AS all_rids
FROM users;
```

Comment: Cool. The only problem... it seems to only return rows where there is a match in the group_concat()  (I guess an inner join?) I also need to return rows of users where there is -no- match for that inner join (left join?)

Comment: @jchwebdev . . . This query should return all rows in `users`, regardless of whether or not there are any rows in `users_roles`.

Answer (score 0):

Why you Don't simply use a LEFT JOIN?

```
    SELECT users.uid, users.name,
           users.pass, users.mail, users.created,
           users_roles.rid
      FROM users
 LEFT JOIN users_roles ON users.uid=users_roles.uid
```